# How to customize a HTML Editor

Tags: css, javafx, html-editor

How can I go about changing the background color of the text input area in a HTML Editor in JavaFX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the text of the html editor, specifying the appropriate background color in a style.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ColoredBackground extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
        editor.setHtmlText("<body style='background-color: papayawhip;'/>");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(editor));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image: papaya]

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe this is possible. Drilling down into HTMLEditorSkin shows that the 'text input area' of the HTMLEditor is a WebView, which doesn't seem to contain a CSSMetaData entry for styling.

Comment: I should be more specific: The WebView of the HTMLEditor is not styleable from .css